# How to include slick API implicits in a function?

Tags: scala, slick

I am implementing a function to create tables as needed using slick 3.1.0, like below:

```
  def ensureTables(db: backend.DatabaseDef, ts: Seq[TableQuery[_]]) {
    val ts0 = Await.result(db.run(MTable.getTables), Duration.Inf)
    val ns = Set() ++ ts0.map(t => t.name.name)

    for {
      t <- ts
    } Await.result(db.run(t.schema.create), Duration.Inf)
  }
```

It is not finished yet due to compilation errors (I wanted to add filters to the for expression).  The error is at the seventh line: `value schema is not a member of slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.api.TableQuery[_$1]`.  It is because the implicit functions defined in [`SQLiteDriver.API`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/api/index.html#slick.driver.JdbcProfile$API) (`tableQueryToTableQueryExtensionMethods` in this case) does not get included.

How do I include those implicit functions properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to make my db code pluggable with different drivers in slick I usually parametrise my functions (or traits/classes) with the profile type and provide the profile as an argument; in your case the function would look something like this:

```
def ensureTables[P <: JdbcProfile](profile: P)(db: profile.api.Database, ts: Seq[TableQuery[_]]) {
  import profile.api._
  ...
}
```

If the function is in a trait or class that aggregates database-related functions you can provide the profile at the class level and import there.

As an aside, please note that you block two threads and potentially cause deadlocks every time you use an `Await`; use future combinators like `flatMap` to write asynchronous code instead.

Comment: Hi Aldo, I tried this solution but it didn't work.  However commenting doesn't seem to be appropriate for describing what I saw, so I am writing the details in an answer below.

Comment: Hi Aldo, after some investigations I have finally resolved the issue.  I'll still write the details, but your solution is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

Note: **This is not a new answer, it only elaborates the answer provided by Aldo Stracquadanio.**  It is written as an answer so that more details can be shown in a friendly way.

At first, I tried the following version, which was the result of simply applying Aldo's hint:

```
def ensureTables[P <: JdbcProfile]
                (profile: P)
                (db: profile.api.Database, ts: Seq[TableQuery[_]]) {
  import profile.api._
  val ts0 = Await.result(db.run(MTable.getTables), Duration.Inf)
  val ns = Set() ++ ts0.map(t => t.name.name)
  for (t <- ts) Await.result(db.run(t.schema.create), Duration.Inf)
}
```

The error was still there, as the type of `ts` was wrong: the type required by `tableQueryToTableQueryExtensionMethods` is `Query[T, U, Seq] with TableQuery[T]`, and not `TableQuery[_]`, so no implicits were eligible for the above definition.

A correct version of `ensureTables` should be implemented as this:

```
def ensureTables[P <: RelationalProfile, T <: RelationalProfile#Table[_], C[_]]
                (profile: P)
                (db: profile.api.Database,
                 ts: Seq[Query[T, _, C] with TableQuery[T]]) {
  import profile.api._
  val ts0 = Await.result(db.run(MTable.getTables), Duration.Inf)
  val ns = Set() ++ ts0.map(t => t.name.name)
  for (t <- ts) Await.result(db.run(t.schema.create), Duration.Inf)
}
```

This function itself compiles.  However, when I tried to put several `TableQuery` values together and use it, I got two new errors:

```
ensureTables(profile)(db, Seq(circles, rectangles))
```

resulted in

```
[error] SlickProg.scala:40: no type parameters for method ensureTables: (db: slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.profile.api.Database, ts: Seq[slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.api.Query[T, _, C] with slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.api.TableQuery[T]])Unit exist so that it can be applied to arguments (slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.backend.DatabaseDef, Seq[slick.lifted.TableQuery[_ >: slab.Rectangles with slab.Circles <: slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.Table[_ >: (Int, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double) with (Int, Double, Double, Double) <: Product with Serializable]]])
[error]  --- because ---
[error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[error]  found   : Seq[slick.lifted.TableQuery[_ >: slab.Rectangles with slab.Circles <: slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.Table[_ >: (Int, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double) with (Int, Double, Double, Double) <: Product with Serializable]]]
[error]  required: Seq[slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.api.Query[?T, _, ?C] with slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.api.TableQuery[?T]]
[error]     (which expands to)  Seq[slick.lifted.Query[?T, _, ?C] with slick.lifted.TableQuery[?T]]
[error]     ensureTables(profile)(db, Seq(circles, rectangles))
[error]                 ^
[error] SlickProg.scala:40: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Seq[slick.lifted.TableQuery[_ >: slab.Rectangles with slab.Circles <: slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.Table[_ >: (Int, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double) with (Int, Double, Double, Double) <: Product with Serializable]]]
[error]  required: Seq[slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.api.Query[T, _, C] with slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.api.TableQuery[T]]
[error]     (which expands to)  Seq[slick.lifted.Query[T, _, C] with slick.lifted.TableQuery[T]]
[error]     ensureTables(profile)(db, Seq(circles, rectangles))
[error]                                  ^
[error] two errors found
```

It was due to putting values of different types into a single sequence resulting in an unexpectedly typed sequence.  The compiler computed a common type (`_ >: slab.Rectangles with slab.Circles <: slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.Table[_ >: (Int, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double) with (Int, Double, Double, Double) <: Product with Serializable]`) for the elements of the sequence.

I end up with the following implementation, to iterate over the tables from outside the `ensureTable` function:

```
def ignore[T](x: T): Unit = ()

def valueOf[T](f: Future[T]): T = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)

def ensureTable[P <: RelationalProfile, T <: RelationalProfile#Table[_], C[_]]
               (p: P)
               (db: p.api.Database, ns: Set[String],
                t: Query[T, _, C] with TableQuery[T]) {
  import p.api._
  val n = t.shaped.value.tableName
  if (!ns.contains(n))
    ignore(valueOf(db.run(t.schema.create)))
}

def tablesOf[P <: RelationalProfile](p: P)(db: p.api.Database): Seq[MTable] =
   valueOf(db.run(MTable.getTables))

val names = Set() ++ tablesOf(profile)(db).map(_.name.name)
for (t <- Seq(circles, rectangles)) ensureTable(profile)(db, names, t)
```

Thank you Aldo Stracquadanio.